# Updating Window position in PySDL2 (Help!)

Tags: python, window, pysdl2

I'm currently trying to change the position of a Window I created in PySDL2, after it has been already rendered.

I've tried updating the `Window.position` attribute of the Window. But despite doing this, and having the surface refresh itself, no change is visible. (The window stays where it was originally drawn).

I know I can change the window position though, because if I change the position in the window's creation line, it will change when it's initially drawn on the screen. (You just don't seem to be able to change it after)

**Code:**

```
import sdl2
import sdl2.ext
import sys

White = sdl2.ext.Color(255,255,255)
Red = sdl2.ext.Color(153,0,0)

class Background(sdl2.ext.SoftwareSpriteRenderSystem):
    def __init__(self,window):
        super(Background,self).__init__(window)
        sdl2.ext.fill(self.surface,sdl2.ext.Color(0,33,66))



def main():
    sdl2.ext.init() # Initialze 
    world = sdl2.ext.World() # Create World
    W = sdl2.ext.Window("Default",size=(400,300), position = None,flags = sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS) # Create Window


    BG = Background(W)
    world.add_system(BG)
    W.show()
    running = True
    while running:
        events = sdl2.ext.get_events()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == sdl2.SDL_QUIT:
                running = False
                break
            if event.type == sdl2.SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                X,Y = (300,100)                       # NEW COORDINATES
                print("Updating: . . ")
                W.position = X,Y                      # Updating the coordinates
                print(W.position)    
                W.hide()                       # Tried hiding and showing the window
                W.show()                       # Didn't help unfortunately
        W.refresh()   # Refresh the window. 
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

My attempt is simply to update the .position attribute of the window. But like I stated earlier, nothing seems to happen.

**EDIT: According to [this](http://devcry.heiho.net/2009/09/dragging-sdlnoframe-borderless-window.html) blog post. It's pretty much impossible.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PySDL2's Window class](http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/sdl2ext_window.html) does not feature a position attribute up to version 0.9.2. This is the reason, why your code does not work. If you are using SDL2's **SDL_SetWindowPosition()** function directly, the window can be positioned, *if your window manager/operating system supports it (especially important for X11 and e.g. tiling window managers)*.

Change your code

```
print("Updating: . . ")
W.position = X,Y                      # Updating the coordinates
print(W.position)
```

to

```
print("Updating: . . ")
sdl2.SDL_SetWindowPosition(W.window, X, Y)
```

and it should work, given positioning the window is supported.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I had actually tried this once earlier. But I had kept putting W, instead of W.window. This would give you an error that said: "LP_SDL_Window instance instead of Window", and I gave up with that then. Thanks so much!